# Stripe ACH Instant Account Validation without Financial Connections

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

We're facing an issue where a competitor is offering instant account validation by collecting a customer's account and routing number and it is instantly verified without opening the Financial Connections window.

We feel that is a much easier flow for ACH but the problem I am facing is while Stripe in their documentation mentions how to manually collect bank and routing numbers and verify them via microdeposits it does not anywhere show how to verify them instantly without collecting microdeposits.

If you've done this integration in the past would be super helpful if you can guide us on it. Link to the doc I am following in stripe: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?web-or-mobile=web&payments-ui-type=direct-api

Comment: Is it possible your competitor is using https://plaid.com/? They offer this feature.

Comment: You should contact Stripe Support for guidance: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: No, they explicitly mention they're using stripe @ceejayoz

Comment: @NolanH I've tried their chat support but it is not that helpful, they're not that much aware of technical implementations

Comment: @FahadSohail And https://docs.stripe.com/financial-connections/ach-direct-debit-payments#enable `verification_method=instant` doesn't do it? https://docs.stripe.com/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_options-us_bank_account-verification_method

Comment: @ceejayoz no, that gives the error "Payment method data is not allowed when payment_method_options[us_bank_account][verification_method]=instant is used."  I think this is because we're sending bank and routing numbers

Comment: @ceejayoz "Is it possible your competitor is using plaid.com? They offer this feature" That was my thought as well. Stripe used to have a partnered integration with them, documented here: https://docs.stripe.com/ach-deprecated#using-plaid